# How to rewrite URL using htacess file

Tags: url-rewriting

I am struuggling to rewrite part of the URL using .htaccess file.

Here is the URL which is loaded from public/html: *https://www.someurl.co.uk/someurl.php*

I need to be able to Add this dynamic string which is loaded from the server and append to the static url above (someurl.co.uk): **/#!/Products/q:/category:121/page:1**

In total, the url needs to load a static url to all dynamic urls: https://www.someurl.co.uk/someurl.php/#!/Products/q:/category:121/page:1

Is this possible?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try below script

```
RewriteRule ^someurl.php/Products/(.+)/category/(.+)/page/(.+) /someurl.php?products=$1&category=$1&page=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Hi Shantun, apologies i should of been more clearer, the dynamic string above is an example. How can i make it dynamic to append any URL to the static public URL?